# Importing from custom package fails in Python

Tags: python

So I have a `main.py file` inside `/home/richard/projects/hello-python` directory:

```
import sys
   sys.path.append('/home/richard/projects/hello-python')

   from Encode  import Ffmpeg
   x = Ffmpeg()
   x.encode()
```

I have then created a package in the `/home/richard/projects/hello-python/Encode` directory:

```
__init__.py
Ffmpeg.py
```

Init file is empty. `Ffmpeg.py` file contains:

```
class Ffmpeg(object):


   i = 150

   def __init__(self):
       print "i am constructor"

   def encode(self):
       print "hello world"
```

Now I run the `main.py` script like this:

```
python main.py
```

I get this output:

```
richard@richard-desktop:~/projects/hello-python$ python main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    x = Ffmpeg()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
richard@richard-desktop:~/projects/hello-python$
```

I think there is some problem with my `sys.path` so my module cannot be imported correctly but I am not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from Encode.Ffmpeg import Ffmpeg
```

Comment: And to answer why: the error you get states that Ffmpeg is seen as a module which is represented by the Ffmpeg.py file. You really wanted a class which is IN that module. Both names are the same which is nothing wrong but could be confusing.

Comment: The Python 3 stdlib generally uses the convention that *file/module* names are all lowercase (and changed just to avoid this sort of confusion with an uppercased *class* name that is otherwise the same. If you adopted this, the import would be `from encode.ffmpeg import Ffmpeg`.